# How to get the sum() query result of MS Access in php

Tags: php, database, ms-access

How can i get the sum() query value in php?. I'm using MS Access DB.

My Code:

```
$sql="select sum(col1) from table1 where Id=$id";
$rs=odbc_exec($con,$sql);
odbc_fetch_row($rs);
```

Now i want to get the result of this query. How can i get it?

I tried like `echo odbc_result($rs,"col1");`

But it gives me an error as  `odbc_result(): Field Present not found`

Help me out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with -

```
$sql="select sum(col1) as col_sum from table1 where Id=$id";
```

And access by -

```
echo odbc_result($rs,"col_sum");
```